# how to aggregate by YEAR() in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using this code to aggregate rows from database:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models import FloatField
query_set=testTable.objects.filter(location='TgR',\
          part__in=['Q', 'F'],week_number__lte=38,week_number__gte=42).\
      annotate(col1_avg=Avg('col1'),col2_avg=Avg('col2'),col3_avg=Avg('col3'),\
      Total= (Avg('col1',output_field=FloatField())+Avg('col2', output_field=FloatField())+Avg('col3', output_field=FloatField()))
     )
```

raw query looks like this:

```
SELECT week_number, part, type,  AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), ( AVG(col1) + AVG(col2) + AVG(col3) ) as Total
FROM table1
WHERE location = 'TgR'
AND week_number BETWEEN 38 AND 42
AND part IN ('Q', 'F')
GROUP BY 1 ,2 ,3;
```

And I want to change it to :

```
SELECT YEAR(date), week_number, part, type,  AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), ( AVG(col1) + AVG(col2) + AVG(col3) ) as Total
FROM table1
WHERE location = 'TgR'
AND week_number BETWEEN 38 AND 42
AND part IN ('Q', 'F')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Basically all I want to do is add that Year to aggregate, but have no idea how to do this right.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

django has a whole section and concept about aggregations.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/